# How to change the default marker pattern size in JSARToolkit

Tags: artoolkit, ar.js, jsartoolkit

According from [this guide from ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_training#changing_marker_pattern_size), the default marker pattern size is 16x16. Is it possible to be able to modify it to 32x32 in JSARToolkit?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add the `arPattCreateHandle2` function to the emscripten bindings https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/emscripten/ARBindEM.cpp

similar to, for example, this function https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/emscripten/ARBindEM.cpp#L67

And write a binding function for it in `ARToolKitJS.cpp` like here https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/emscripten/ARToolKitJS.cpp#L482

I think you also need to add it to the `FUNCTIONS` array (https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5/blob/master/js/artoolkit.api.js#L1578)

Then you need to rebuild the library using emscripten.
For rebuild I wrote the guide in the readme on artoolkitX (https://github.com/artoolkitx/jsartoolkit5) which is easiest to follow if you use the Docker root. Otherwise, you need to setup emscripten on your local machine.

If you already use emscripten locally you can simply do `npm run build` from the jsartoolkit root.

I'm actively maintaining the artoolkitX repo and I'm certain that it builds meaning you should clone from there.

Let me know how it goes.